# Open, create files and save data in client side and reuse that data

Tags: javascript, io, google-chrome-app

I am creating a chrome app with plain javascript and bootstrap. Initially user have to give some data and app keeps that data and reuse that for next times. I think I have to store that 
data in a file. Can I use the plain javascript file IO to do that or is there a special way to do it in chrome-style. (Because some features are disabled in packaged apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that localstorage is not enabled for Chrome packaged apps. However, depending on what kind of data you're managing, there are two APIs that should work.

[`chrome.storage.local`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) is a general key-value store that will save data on the local machine (`chrome.storage.sync` is an identical API that will also synchronize the data between a users' devices, but I wouldn't recommend it for large files)

The API is simple to use:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({myKey: "myValue"}, function() {
    if (!chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log("The value has been stored!");
    } else {
        console.error("There was an error!");
    }
});

chrome.storage.local.get("myKey", function(data) {
    if (!chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log("The value is " + data.myKey);
    } else {
        console.error("There was an error!");
    }
});
```

(If you're using chrome.storage.sync, then you probably also want to add a listener to the `chrome.storage.onChanged` event, to know when data was changed from another location)

The other way may be what you're thinking of as "plain javascript file IO" -- the [W3C File System API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/) is supported by packaged apps. You can request storage space from the user and store actual files that you can read and write in JavaScript. There's a good introduction to it [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

Comment: I used 
chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': 'theValue'}, function() {
        console.log('Settings saved');
    });
how can I get the values ina function call. API gives ans example
retrieving data, when onChange event occurs only.

Comment: I've added a couple of sample snippets showing how to get and set values.